# How to justify a paragraph inside a muilti-line text form control in "openoffice writer" or "libreoffice writer"

Tags: forms, libreoffice

I want to justify a paragraph inside a multi-line text form control using OpenOffice writer or LibreOffice writer. Inside control  properties it only shows me this options for  align the paragraph:

1. Default
2. Left
3. Right
4. Center

But I wonder is there any way to justify the paragraph.

[image: Not Justified]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask about this.

Nevertheless, you should be able to justify the text by selecting it and pressing the [Justify shortcut](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Shortcut_Keys_for_Writer) (`Ctrl+J`).

Comment: (Ctrl + J) works only in text that is not inside of "Form Controls", I tried to use this shortcut inside the "Text Box Form Control" but it does not work.  :-(